# overriding the template base method in derived class?

Tags: c++, c++11, class-template

Suppose I have a base class as below:

```
template <typename T>
class Base {
    // implementation
    void do_something() { /* ... */ } ;
};
```

then, I create a `Derived` class as below, and override the `do_something()` method:

```
template <typename T>
class Derived : public Base<T> {
    // implementation
    void do_something() { /* ... */ } ;
};
```

I know virtualization does not work in class templates, and I am just hiding the implementation of the methods.  but I do want to store a bunch of derived classes and base classes into a vector, (I do not want to use type erasure, or polymorphism),

my question is, given that `static_cast` of `Derived` class to base class gives me the `do_something` of based class, Is there any way that I can store them as base classes while each has their implementation of `do_something()` class ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little variation of the melpomene's answer (adding a no-template base struct, `BaseOfBase`, for the `Base<T>` structs) permit the use of a common vector of base of derived classe of different `T` types.

A working example

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct BaseOfBase
 { virtual void do_something () = 0; };

template <typename T>
struct Base : public BaseOfBase
 {
   T val;

   void do_something ()
    { std::cout << "Base::do_something() [" << val << "]\n"; };
 };

template <typename T>
struct Derived : public Base<T>
 { void do_something()
    { std::cout << "Derived::do_something() [" << this->val << "]\n"; } };

int main ()
 {
   std::vector<BaseOfBase*> vpbb;

   Base<int>            bi;
   Derived<int>         di;
   Base<std::string>    bs;
   Derived<std::string> ds;

   bi.val = 1;
   di.val = 2;
   bs.val = "foo";
   ds.val = "bar";

   vpbb.push_back(&bi);
   vpbb.push_back(&di);
   vpbb.push_back(&bs);
   vpbb.push_back(&ds);

   for ( auto const & pbb : vpbb )
      pbb->do_something();
 }
```

Comment: OP said - _I do not want to use type erasure, **or polymorphism**_.

Comment: @skypjack - yes, but said also "I know virtualization does not work in class templates"

Comment: Fair enough. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

> but I do want to store a bunch of derived classes and base classes into a vector, (I do not want to use type erasure, or polymorphism),

This is already just not possible in C++. In C++, a vector can only contain objects of the same static type. The only way a vector can contain different types of objects is if their static type is still the same, but they have different dynamic types, but this is type erasure/polymorphism which you said you don't want to use.

I think maybe you need to rethink your requirements, because your question in essence reads: I want to do something, but I don't want to use technique X which is explicitly defined as the only way to do that something in C++!

Answer (score 3):

I did this and it seems to work fine:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct Base {
    virtual void do_something() { std::cout << "Base::do_something()\n"; }
};

template <typename T>
struct Derived : public Base<T> {
    virtual void do_something() { std::cout << "Derived::do_something()\n"; }
};

int main() {
    Base<int> b;
    Derived<int> d;
    Base<int> *p;
    p = &b;
    p->do_something();
    p = &d;
    p->do_something();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Base::do_something()
Derived::do_something()
```

Answer (score 0):

When we say virtualization doesn't work in template classes, we don't mean that you can't do virtual functions in a template class, nor does it mean that you cannot override a member function with a specialized version of it.

@melpomene showed an example of overriding in general, and I will show here with specialization:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class Base {
    public:
        virtual T do_something(T in) { std::cout << "Base::do_something()\n"; return in; }
};


class Derived : public Base<int> {
    public:
        virtual int do_something(int in) { std::cout << "Derived::do_something()\n"; return in - 1; }
};

void main()
{
    Base<int> b;
    Derived d;
    Base<int> *p = &b;
    auto r1 = p->do_something(10);
    std::cout << r1 <<std::endl;
    p = &d;
    auto r2 = p->do_something(10);
    std::cout << r2 << std::endl;        
}
```

Which will output

```
Base::do_something()                                                                                                        
10                                                                                                                          
Derived::do_something()                                                                                                     
9
```

Showing that it perfectly works as expected.

What we do mean when saying that

> virtualization does not work in class templates

Basically means that you can't use as a template the derived class when the base is expected.

Consider the above classes `Base<T>` and `Derived`, then if we have the following code:

```
#include <memory>

template <typename T>
void Test(std::unique_ptr<Base<T>> in){ std::cout << "This will not work with derived"; }

void main()
{
    Base<int> b;
    Derived d; 

    auto ptr = std::unique_ptr<Derived>(&d);
    Test(ptr); // <-- Will fail to compile as an invalid argument
}
```

it will fail because `std::unique_ptr<Derived>` does not inherit from `std::unique_ptr<Base<T>>` although `Derived` itself inherits from `Base<T>`.